# Coded UI Tests Built In VS 2013 Not Running In VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

I have a series of hand coded projects which were built in VS 2013, and after transitioning to VS 2015, I can no longer run the tests. When I try to run or debug them, it seems the test runner skips or aborts them. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you built them again with VS 2015?

Comment: Yep, no dice. I'm going to try deleting the solution and remapping to ensure I don't have any DLLs in the folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, basically what I ended up doing is forcefully redirecting all the testing assembly versions via the projects app.config. It kind of sucks though because you'll have to comment out the redirection on your local, and ensure the version that is checked in to source control has the redirections uncommented. It's a hack, but so far that's how I've been able to make it work.

Here's what I pasted into the app.config:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WindowsStore.CodedUITestFramework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WindowsStore.UITest.Common" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WindowsStore.UITest.Extension" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.ExtensionUtilities" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WindowsStore.UITesting" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WindowsStore.UITest.Playback" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>


  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WindowsStore.UITest.Framework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="UiaComWrapper.WindowsStore" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="UiaComWrapper" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

Build tests with VS 2015. Then you can again execute them, but only from VS 2015. You execute always with the same version, with which you build.